# Hiding a private field from reflection in .net

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, private, private-members

I have a class that performs some sensitive I/O operations across an entire disk volume. By sensitive I mean if the operation goes wrong, it can potentially corrupt the target volume.

During some post-release testing, I found that the process can be corrupted using reflection to manipulate private fields. The class is not `sealed` by design so that consumers of the library can create derivatives.

Is there a way to secure private members to prevent modification via reflection (from derived or consumer code)?

**UPDATE:** I found a comment from [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) to an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20880941/938668) mentioning `[ReflectionPermission]`. Looking into that now.

Comment: You cannot stop someone from using reflection.

Comment: @Arran: Of course not. My question is about whether the CLR provides a safety mechanisms to prevent access to marked private members.

Comment: The answer is still no!

Comment: If your customers want to corrupt their volumes, they have easier ways to do that than hacking your software.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to hide your field from Reflection.  It can be used to access and manipulate any field on a type.  There are steps you can take like obfuscation which make it harder to identify fields and in turn harder to change via Reflection.  This is only a speed bump though.  A determined developer can use Reflection to beat any work arounds you have

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: **No**.

You cannot stop people from messing with your program if they have the privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your best effort is going to be in obfuscating the code. Otherwise, you cannot stop someone from using reflection to mar things up a bit.

There is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857685/how-to-create-own-dotnet-obfuscator) which may give you some idea on how you want to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

`Private` is just private to developers consuming your class. You **cannot** prevent its access via reflection.